# In my Jquery DateBox a text "Grid" is appearing above icon

Tags: jquery, datebox

In my Jquery DateBox a text "Grid" is appearing above icon.
How can remove this.

## Code:

```
 <div style="float:left; width:150px; ">
                            <input class='listItemNoIcon'  id="Date1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-collapsed='false' 
                                data-icon="false" placeholder="start time"
                            data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "overrideTimeFormat": 12, "focusMode": true}'>
                    </div>
```

## In Browser rendered

```
<a title="Open Date Picker" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-d" href="#" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Open Date Picker</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grid ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Hi I got the answer A class in office site is causing problem I have override that as below (ie. included in my custom css)

[data-icon]:before {
    content: none!important;
        }